# How to Keep Secondary Tiles from Disappearing?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have an app for Windows Phone (8.1 using C# WinRT) that can pin secondary tiles to the user's start screen.  It works well so far, and is almost fully functional.

Sometimes after working on the app and making many changes, and then debugging or deploying the app to the actual physical phone device using Visual Studio, all of the tiles currently pinned by the app are removed or disappear.

If the app's main tile is pinned, this is also removed.  The app's user selected settings seem to still be saved on the phone.

For example it seems that changing the app's images and logos used for the visual assets in the app manifest will cause the tiles to disappear, which would make sense I guess for the main tile, but why cause the secondary tiles to also be removed?

What specific kinds of changes will cause the app's secondary pinned tiles to disappear?

Is there a way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Checking @Rudy huyn's [blog](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2012/01/12/additional-tiles-disappear-by-themselves/), "When creating a secondary Tile, the `BackgroundImage` and the `BackBackgroundImage` images must be created using a local resource." And the [guideline for developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465398.aspx) mentions that you should not change the name of your tile's default image asset once your app is published. If Windows cannot find the expected image, it will display a blank tile.

Comment: It seems also that adding a share target removes the app's pinned tiles.

Comment: And also changing the app's capabilities removes the app's pinned tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an issue I faced too while I was working on them.

### The Reason for the issue:

sometimes when you make some changes in the code, visual studio realizes that your code would change a lot app flow because of which it removes the app and then redeploys it (retaining the app local storage data).

### What actually happens:

Because the app was removed and then redeployed the tiles are removed as the application no longer exists in the system and then after it's redeploys you'll need to re-pin the tiles to the start.

### How do you get it solved:

So basically once you stop redeploying your solution and start using the app like it's downloaded from the store (i.e) after release , the secondary tiles would not get removed.

### To summarize:

It's only because the visual studio redeploys you app that the secondary tiles get unpinned. You would have noticed it doesn't happen everytime, it just happens a few times when you change a lot of things.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.